# I want to insert employee id in address table(child table)-one to many concept

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am using `Java Jdbc connection`.

My question is very simple, I am inserted the employee record in a employee table
Ex:

```
Insert into employee (emp_id,emp_name) values(10,'hello');
```

How could I fetch the foreign key for child table(`address`) and insert it?

If I use `select max(emp_id) from employee` and Insert the id into child table
I'm afraid of if more than one person try to insert the values in employee table and there is a possibilities that I can get a wrong employee id for the child table.
Is there any possible way to insert the employee id in child table.

Note:I require a sql query for how to insert the employee id in child table

Comment: for child table example:Insert into address (foreignkey_employee_id,door_no,street name);

Comment: yes,I require for auto increment only

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a record into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column, you can obtain the value stored into that column by calling the mysql_insert_id() function.

More details to refer this link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: The OP wants to have JAVA, not PHP ?

Comment: The question is tagged with `JAVA` and thus the OP wants to have a JAVA code and not a PHP function. `mysql_insert_id()` isn't any JAVA "function" (as there are no functions at all in JAVA). And the linked example in the manual is showing a `C` code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things.

Assumed, your primary key in `employee` is *not* an AUTO_INCREMENT with the name `emp_id` and your inserting like `Insert into employee (emp_id,emp_name) values(10,'hello');` you're done: the foreign key is `10`.

BUT: if it is really an AUTO_INCREMENT, you *must not* specify any value for it:

`Insert into employee (emp_name) values('Veronica');`

You may then retrieve the last generated `emp_id` value by the driver or by a subsequent SQL statement. In JAVA, you need to tell the driver, that you want to have the last generated ID back:

```
 PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Then you are able to fetch the generated primary key:

```
 ResultSet rset = pst.getGeneratedKeys();
 Long emp_id;
 if (rset.next()) {
    emp_id = rset.getLong(1);
 }
```

Now `Long emp_id` contains the foreign key to insert in to address table.

Comment: your answer is very helpful,so in this case even though multiple users try to insert the record it will not fetch the wrong employee id right?

Comment: Yes. The driver assures that this is atomic from the view of one single instance.